# can i get the error in scala flatMap or map (or anything without case which is more elegant)?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Can I catch both the failure and success in scala `map` / `flatMap` so that I use them instead of `case Success` `case Failure`? code with `map` / `flatMap` looks better than `case ..`

in the example below, is it possible to express the below only with `map` / `flatMap` / **or other methods except for `case`** without any `case`? (would it be more elegant then?)

```
Try(doSomething()) match {
  case Failure(thrown) => {
    Console.println("Failure: " + thrown)
  }
  case Success(s) => {
    Console.println(s)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the api: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.Try.  `Try` has `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, `getOrElse`, etc, as well as some stuff like `recover`, that are particular to `Try`.

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def doSomething() = 1
Try(doSomething()).recover{ case e => "Failure: " + e }.foreach(println)

def doSomethingBad(): Int = sys.error("x")
Try(doSomethingBad()).recover{ case e => "Failure: " + e }.foreach(println)
```